# how to get an event's completion time in jquery

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery

hi i am using jquery .

i have a check box click event

```
jQuery('.btn-check-box').click(function () {

    //code goes here .
});
```

the problem is the click event takes considerable time to complete.some times the browser gets stuck.
so i want to change the code inside the function and reduce the completion time .

now i want to get my current click event completion time . 
then make changes to the code and again check the completion time .

so i can optimize my code according to the completion time .

**is there any way to check an events completion time .** 
please help.
thanks in advance.

Comment: can't you do something like `finishtime-starttime`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pass event as argument.

```
var createdTime;
jQuery('.btn-check-box').click(function(e){ 
  createdTime = e.timeStamp;
}).done(function(){ calculate time difference });
```

if you will use `console.log(e)` then it will show you that jQuery already passing timestamp when event is triggered.

so now you need to find a way when even is getting done so `.done()` jQuery method will help you.

In side .done() you can also get same `e.timestamp` and do some math on to get your desired out put in second, minutes or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Like SrinivasR said, finish time - start time.

```
jQuery('.btn-check-box').click(function () {
    var t0 = (new Date()).getTime();
    //code goes here
    console.log("Event took",(new Date()).getTime() - t0, "ms to complete.");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following for your code

```
jQuery('.btn-check-box').click(function () {
var secondStart = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    // Your code goes here .
var secondEnd = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
var totalTime = secondEnd - secondStart;
console.log('Executing took' +totalTime +'seconds' )
});
```